# Wrong member operator is deduced over the correct global one

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have a 3x3 `Matrix` and a 3x1 `Vector` classes. I have two multiplication operators; one for multiplying a matrix with a scalar, another for multiplying a matrix with a vector object. The matrix-scalar multiplication operator is member inside the `Matrix` class and the matrix-vector multiplication operator is global.

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <array>

template <class T>
class Matrix
{
    public:
        Matrix(std::initializer_list<T> List);
        Matrix() : Matrix({0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}) {}

        template <class S>                      // THE COMPILER TRIES TO USE
        Matrix<T> operator*(const S & Scalar);  // THIS OPERATOR IN BOTH CASES.

        const T & operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const;

    private:
        static constexpr size_t SIZE = 3;
        static constexpr size_t AREA = SIZE * SIZE;
        std::array<T, AREA> E;
};

template <class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(std::initializer_list<T> List)
{
    if (List.size() != AREA) throw("Error!");
    for (size_t i=0; i<AREA; i++)
    {
        E[i] = *(List.begin() + i);
    }
}

template <class T>
const T & Matrix<T>::operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const
{
    return E[SIZE * j + i];
}

template <class T>
template <class S>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator*(const S & Scalar)
{
    const T ScalarT = static_cast<T>(Scalar);
    Matrix<T> Result;
    for (size_t i=0; i<AREA; i++)
    {
        Result.E[i] = E[i] * ScalarT;
    }
    return Result;
}

template <class T>
class Vector
{
    public:
        Vector(std::initializer_list<T> List);
        Vector() : Vector({0,0,0}) {};
        const T & operator()(size_t i) const;
              T & operator()(size_t i);

    private:
        static constexpr size_t SIZE = 3;
        std::array<T, SIZE> E;
};

template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(std::initializer_list<T> List)
{
    if (List.size() != SIZE) throw("Error!");
    for (size_t i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        E[i] = *(List.begin() + i);
    }
}

template <class T>
const T & Vector<T>::operator()(size_t i) const
{
    return E[i];
}

template <class T>
T & Vector<T>::operator()(size_t i)
{
    return E[i];
}

template <class T>  // THE COMPILER NEVER TRIES USING THIS GLOBAL OPERATOR.
Vector<T> operator*(const Matrix<T> & Mat, const Vector<T> & Vec)
{
    Vector<T> Result;
    Result(0) = Mat(0,0) * Vec(0) + Mat(0,1) * Vec(1) + Mat(0,2) * Vec(2);
    Result(1) = Mat(1,0) * Vec(0) + Mat(1,1) * Vec(1) + Mat(1,2) * Vec(2);
    Result(2) = Mat(2,0) * Vec(0) + Mat(2,1) * Vec(1) + Mat(2,2) * Vec(2);
    return Result;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[]/*, wchar_t *envp[]*/)
{
    Matrix<float> Mat1({2,  0,  0,
                        0,  2,  0,
                        0,  0,  2});

    Vector<float> Vec1({1,
                        2,
                        3});

    Matrix<float> Mat2 = Mat1 * 2;      // Matrix-Scalar Multiplication
    Vector<float> Vec2 = Mat1 * Vec1;   // Matrix-Vector Multiplication

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, when I try to do a matrix-vector multiplication, the compiler chooses and tries to use the matrix-scalar multiplication operator, and gives a compiler error.

If I delete the matrix-scalar multiplication operator and the line where I use it, the program runs successfully. In reverse, if I delete the matrix-vector multiplication operator, it again runs successfully. They just don't get along. And when it runs (in either case), it makes the all calculations correctly.

What is going wrong here?

Compiler & IDE: Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Comment: Could you produce a minimal example? This has a lot of unnecessary details.

Comment: @TartanLlama My real consists of HUGE matrix and vector classes. I carried here only the necessary functions that I will use in this minimal example. This is already a very simplified version. I don't know where else I can cut.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Ah, sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: `template<class S>` ... `(const S&)` matches all objects .  It doesn't mean "only scalar types" or something

Comment: Overload resolution gets very complicated when you have member and non-member versions of the same operator. I strongly recommend only using non-member `operator*`.  (This probably won't fix your problem but it may remove some red herrings or confounding factors)

Comment: Make it `Matrix<T> operator*(const S & Scalar) const`.

Comment: @M.M or change the order of type definitions and make both member functions. Or just use `T` instead of a different template parameter.

Comment: @hkBattousai Any special reason you don't just accept `T` for your member operator?

Comment: @M.M partial ordering makes `const Vector<T>&` the preferred one over `const S&`, nothing *gets complicated* in member vs. nonmember operators, at least here the member `operator*` should be probably const qualified, though clang still finds that ambiguous

Comment: @SimonKraemer No particular reason. I just wanted to make it as generic as possible.

Comment: @hkBattousai Change it to only accepting `T` will solve your problem. It should also be less error-prone. Passing e.g. a pointer doesn't make any sense but works with your current approach. But also take care of things like const-correctness and other things mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: @hkBattousai [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e50e655bd9851889) is what I'd call a minimal example.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki looks like a clang bug to me.

Comment: @TartanLlama You missed a `return *this;` in the member operator ;-)

Comment: @n.m. well I'm not entirely sure. In the global version, `T` is used twice, for `Matrix` and `Vector`, so clang may think that none is more specialized than another one, hence the ambiguity. `Matrix<float>` is more specialized than `Matrix<T>`, just like `const Vector<T>&` is more specialized than `const S&`

Comment: @hkBattousai the easiest and most portable solution is to make the member `operator*` a global one, and let `T` of `Matrix<T>` be deduced (just like in the `Vector<T>`-version)

Comment: @Piotr it is not clear whether float should enter the picture. Are we partial-ordering `Matrix<float>::operator*` or `Matrix<T>::operator*`?

Comment: @n.m. I guess when one uses `Matrix<float>`, then the compiler ends up with two overloads: `template<class S> operator*(const Matrix<float>&, const S&)` and `template<class T> operator*(const Matrix<T>&, const Vector<T>&)`, i.e., the compiler sees `float`, since `Matrix<float>` is an implicit object parameter

Comment: @Piotr Evidently gcc and msvc think otherwise.

Comment: @n.m. yes I know, and I can't tell for sure who is right, though I support clang

Comment: @Piotr Now I've found a case of three compilers making three different decisions. http://pastebin.com/Bp8Us9EA

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki clang 3.3 used to accept this program, 3.5 does not. A bug fix or a new bug?

Comment: @n.m. clang accepts the code you pasted a link to (selecting the member operator, which I agree with), are you sure it fails with 3.5 ?

Comment: Yes, clang accepts, gcc rejects, and msvc accepts and selects the standalone operator.

Answer (score 0):

The language doesn't specify that when searching for overloads to examine all possible scopes. As soon as one candidate is found, only the overloads in that scope are used to select the best candidate. If that candidate fails to compile for other reasons, it still won't examine additional scopes.

So in your case since the scalar is a template parameter it will match any type so as long as the left-hand operand of the operator is a `Matrix<T>`, the scalar multiplication will match any right-hand operand.

You could:

- Just make both `operator*` at the same scope so they're both considered for overload resolution.
- Change the scalar `operator` to take for example a `Scalar<T>` that's a thin wrapper around a scalar type rather than a generic template type.